# RadDropDownTree client side checkboxes (entries area update)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, telerik

I am trying to use Telerik's RadDropDownTree control and I have stucked to a problem.

**What I want to succeed**: I want to select specific nodes (check the **checkboxes** and update the **entries area**) from the drop down tree from client side (on 'click' event).

**HTML**

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree 
    runat="server"
    ID="ddtAtfcDepartment"
    Width="500px"
    Skin="MetroTouch"
    EnableFiltering="true"
    DefaultValue="NULL" 
    CheckBoxes="SingleCheck"
    DataTextField="Descr"
    DataFieldID="ID"
    DataValueField="ID"
    DataFieldParentID="ParentID"
    OnClientDropDownOpening="setDdtWidth"                                                         
    AutoPostBack="false">
    <ButtonSettings ShowClear="true" />
    <DropDownSettings
        Width="99%"
        Height="300px"
        CssClass="shiftsFilterSector"
        CloseDropDownOnSelection="false"
        AutoWidth="Enabled" />
    <FilterSettings Highlight="Matches" EmptyMessage="Πληκτρολογήστε για εύρεση" Filter="Contains" />
</telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

**jQuery**

That's how I'm trying to select the nodes in the list. They actually get checked, but the entries area is empty (not selected).

```
var tree = ddtAtfcDepartment.get_embeddedTree();
var list = [1026,1023]  //The list of values I want to check/select
if (tree && list.length > 0) {                            
    $.each(list, function (i, val) {
        tree.findNodeByValue(val).check();
    });
}
```

I've read [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/dropdowntree/how-to/accessing-the-embedded-tree) that if the checkboxes are enabled, you must use the **SyncEmbeddedTree()** method to update the entries area, but this is server side method and I am unable to find the corresponding client side method.

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?